# Permutation and Combinations Problem.

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are **m** copies of each **n** books on different subjects in the college library. The number of ways in which one or more books can be selected is ...??

I have no idea to deal with this problem , kindly provide me with a hint !!

Comment: Do you count different orders as different?  Can you do some small cases, like the number of ways to select one book and the number of ways to select two books?

Comment: Yes i can , like selecting 2 from "n" books can be represented as n**C**2 .. @RossMillikan

Comment: So there are $mn$ books altogether, all with unique barcodes or something? Do we assume that you never want two copies of the same book?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , 
but no further information is provided.. @Joffan

Comment: nC2 is not correct because you could choose two of the same book (assuming $m \ge 2$)

Answer (score 2):

From the information given you can select any of the $nm$ books available, even if that means selecting more than one of the same title. Assume the selections are without replacement, otherwise the number of possible selections is infinite.

In which case the number of possible selections is $$\binom{nm}{1}+\binom{nm}{2}+...+\binom{nm}{nm}=2^{nm}-1$$

Another way of looking at this is to regard each of the $nm$ books as in one of two possible states - either selected or not selected. This would give $$2^{nm}$$ possiblities, except that we must subtract $1$ since we are not allowed to select no books at all, which can be done in just $1$ way

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  if $n=1$ how many ways are there to select books with no requirement to select at least one?  If $n=2$ you select some number of the first book, then some number of the second. Finally deduct one because you are not allowed to select no books.